# ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype in INSERT INTO... SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

I am coding for a stored procedure for inserting data from a table to another table. I use statement like:

```
Procedure ImportData(
  IMPORT_DATE_FROM date
  ,IMPORT_DATE_TO date  
  ,SEQ_ID int
)
AS
INSERT_DAY nvarchar2(10);
IMPORT_MONTHYEAR nvarchar2(10);
IMPORT_DATE_FROM_INT NUMBER;
IMPORT_DATE_TO_INT NUMBER;
IMPORT_DATE varchar2(20);
--LOG_ID, BATCH_ID have been of type NUMBER and varchar2
IN_LOGID mytable.LOG_ID%TYPE; 
IN_BATCHID mytable.BATCH_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN

IMPORT_DATE_FROM_INT := to_number(to_char(IMPORT_DATE_FROM, 'j'));
IMPORT_DATE_TO_INT := to_number(to_char(IMPORT_DATE_TO, 'j'));

--even assigned it to a nubmer then insert throws exception
IN_LOGID:=10;
IN_BATCHID:10; 
    for cur_r in IMPORT_DATE_FROM_INT ..IMPORT_DATE_TO_INT loop
    IMPORT_DATE := to_char(to_date(cur_r, 'j'), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    INSERT_DAY:=SUBSTR(IMPORT_DATE,9,2);
    IMPORT_MONTHYEAR:=SUBSTR(IMPORT_DATE,1,7);
    INSERT INTO mytable
    (LOGID,BATCHID,TEXT1,TEXT2,TEXT3,...)
    SELECT
    (IN_LOGID,IN_BATCHID, table1.field1, table2.field2,....)
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2
    on table1.dayId= 
    CASE 
    WHEN INSERT_DAY='01' THEN table2.day1
    WHEN INSERT_DAY='02' THEN table2.day2
    ....
    WHEN INSERT_DAY='31' THEN table2.day31
    END
    INNER JOIN table3
    .....
    END LOOP;
```

The problem seems to be at (LOGID&BATCHID) because when I replace "IN_BATCHID"&"IN_LOGID" in the select clause to a hard code 3 (or any number), then the procedure works fine.
I have searched on the web and get information like.

> A value of datatype LONG was used in a function or in a DISTINCT,
>   WHERE, CONNECT BY, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clause. A LONG value can only
>   be used in a SELECT clause.

So I have tried to change my bacthid column from number to varchar2 (and of course the type of the variable IN_BATCHID in the procedure), but the same exception was thrown.

May be it is also useful to mention that for mytable ,TEXT1,TEXT2...are type of VARCHAR2; while table1, table 2 are table of SQL SEVER and of table1.field1 is type of int, table2.field2 is type of varchar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `LONG` in the first place? That has been deprecated over 20 years ago. Use `CLOB` instead

Comment: I am using NUMBER at first and mytable does not contain any field of type long...

Comment: Your error says it does! Either this is not the code throwing the error or you've missed something. Are you sure those text fields (`TEXT1` etc.) are not LONG?

Comment: Just to clarify: `LONG` in Oracle is actually a blob/varchar type of field - it's not  a numeric field (confusing I know)

Comment: You need to look at the types of the columns you are selecting from `table1`, `table2`, etc.

Comment: TEXT1,TEXT2,.. are type of VARCHAR2 but seems that these fields are ok because when I inserting a hard code number to LOGID & BATCHID then the procedure works!

Comment: May be it is useful to mention that for mytable ,TEXT1,TEXT2...are type of VARCHAR2; while table1, table 2 are table of SQL SEVER and of type of int and varchar.

Comment: What are `IN_LOGID` and `IN_BATCHID`?  They aren't declared in the code you've shown.

Comment: Just updated the code.  They are of the same type as the column of mytable. I have also tried simply declared as NUMBER and varchar2 but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly, LONG and LONG RAW data types are deprecated. i recommend you use CLOB, BLOB and BFILE, instead.*

*You may try such a conversion for a LONG data type form varchar2:*

```
declare 
 v_str   varchar(4000); 
 v_lraw  long raw; 
begin
 v_str := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(v_lraw);
 ...
```

*and you could you this `v_str` in your insert statement.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried to change LOGID to BLOB but it fails as invalid alteration of datatype. For conversion, I have tried tochar/to_number  function to make sure the correct type is inserted but no luck.

Comment: @metallic you're welcome. What does it alert during alteration of datatype to BLOB?